# Get started with Latex on Linux

Tags: linux, latex, tex, typesetting

Impressed by [is-latex-worth-learning-today](https://web.archive.org/web/20130816143747/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874576/is-latex-worth-learning-today#), and many how-to's on Windows,

How do you have someone started with LaTeX on Linux?

How do you generate a pdf out of it and give up the OOO Word processer?

Update:

Thanks to all the suggestions given in here. I was able to create an awesome ppt using the Beamer class: http://github.com/becomingGuru/gids-django-ppt. I found this approach too far better than using powerpoint and the like.

Those interested may checkout the [TEX file](http://github.com/becomingGuru/gids-django-ppt/blob/master/contents.tex), with many custom commands and the [corresponding presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/scorpion032/building-pluggable-web-applications-using-django).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, should be on [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Still the number one result when googling

Answer (score 298, accepted):

First you'll need to **Install** it:

- If you're using a distro which packages LaTeX (almost all will do) then look for **texlive** or **tetex**.  TeX Live is the newer of the two, and is replacing tetex on most distributions now.

If you're using Debian or Ubuntu, something like:

```
apt install texlive
```

..will get it installed.

RedHat or CentOS need:

```
yum install tetex
```

*Note : This needs root permissions, so either use `su` to switch user to root, or prefix the commands with `sudo`, if you aren't already logged in as the root user.*

Next you'll need to get a **text editor**.  Any editor will do, so whatever you are comfortable with.  You'll find that advanced editors like Emacs (and vim) add a lot of functionality and so will help with ensuring that your syntax is correct before you try and build your document output.

Create a file called test.tex and put some content in it, say the example from [the LaTeX primer](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/TypicalInput.html):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

The foundations of the rigorous study of \emph{analysis}
were laid in the nineteenth century, notably by the
mathematicians Cauchy and Weierstrass. Central to the
study of this subject are the formal definitions of
\emph{limits} and \emph{continuity}.

Let $D$ be a subset of $\bf R$ and let
$f \colon D \to \mathbf{R}$ be a real-valued function on
$D$. The function $f$ is said to be \emph{continuous} on
$D$ if, for all $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $x \in D$,
there exists some $\delta > 0$ (which may depend on $x$)
such that if $y \in D$ satisfies
\[ |y - x| < \delta \]
then
\[ |f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon. \]

One may readily verify that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous
functions on $D$ then the functions $f+g$, $f-g$ and
$f.g$ are continuous. If in addition $g$ is everywhere
non-zero then $f/g$ is continuous.

\end{document}
```

Once you've got this file you'll need to **run latex** on it to produce some output (as a .dvi file to start with, which is possible to convert to many other formats):

```
latex test.tex
```

This will print a bunch of output, something like this:

```
=> latex test.tex

This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4)
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e &lt;2003/12/01&gt;
Babel &lt;v3.8d&gt; and hyphenation patterns for american, french, german, ngerman, b
ahasa, basque, bulgarian, catalan, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, e
stonian, finnish, greek, icelandic, irish, italian, latin, magyar, norsk, polis
h, portuges, romanian, russian, serbian, slovak, slovene, spanish, swedish, tur
kish, ukrainian, nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
No file test.aux.
[1] (./test.aux) )
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 1508 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

..don't worry about most of this output -- the important part is the **Output written on test.dvi** line, which says that it was successful.

Now you need to **view the output file** with xdvi:

```
xdvi test.dvi &
```

This will pop up a window with the beautifully formatted output in it.  Hit `q' to quit this, or you can leave it open and it will automatically update when the test.dvi file is modified (so whenever you run latex to update the output).

**To produce a PDF of this** you simply run *pdflatex* instead of latex:

```
pdflatex test.tex
```

..and you'll have a test.pdf file created instead of the test.dvi file.

After this is all working fine, I would suggest going to [the LaTeX primer](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer) page and running through the items on there as you need features for documents you want to write.

Future things to consider include:

- *Use tools such as **xfig** or **dia** to create diagrams*.  These can be easily inserted into your documents in a variety of formats.  Note that **if you are creating PDFs then you shouldn't use EPS (encapsulated postscript) for images** -- use pdf exported from your diagram editor if possible, or you can use the `epstopdf` package to automatically convert from (e)ps to pdf for figures included with `\includegraphics`.
- *Start using version control on your documents*.  This seems excessive at first, but being able to go back and look at earlier versions when you are writing something large can be extremely useful.
- *Use **make** to run latex for you*.  When you start on having bibliographies, images and other more complex uses of latex you'll find that you need to run it over multiple files or multiple times (the first time updates the references, and the second puts references into the document, so they can be out-of-date unless you run latex twice...).  Abstracting this into a makefile can save a lot of time and effort.
- *Use a better editor*.  Something like Emacs + AUCTeX is highly competent.  This is of course a highly subjective subject, so I'll leave it at that (that and that Emacs is clearly the best option :)

Comment: Good advice; concrete is always better than vague. I'd remove the latex-dvi path entirely and just mention pdflatex to a beginner.

Comment: (Vector) graphics should be in pdf, when creating pdf latex documents. Though PNGs can be useful if the pdf file is very large.

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring), there are no packages for texlive :(

How can I install texlive on Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) ?

Comment: @valentt This page https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/texlive suggests that texlive should be available (I don't have a 13.04 box immediately to hand to test that this is the case)

Comment: @valentt Actually I did have a 13.04 box around and tried this and an "apt-get install texlive" works fine for me on this version.  Perhaps you are missing an apt repo?

Comment: To lift a Churchill-ism, "it has been said that LaTeX is the worst form of professional documentation except all the others that have been tried", and I agree completely -- I can do everything I need in LaTeX with professional quality, unlike other solutions.

Comment: Use `apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` to bring in bunch of packages you will require little down the line.

Answer (score 39):

To get started with LaTeX on Linux, you're going to need to install a couple of packages:

1. You're going to need a **LaTeX distribution**.  This is the collection of programs that comprise the (La)TeX computer typesetting system.  The standard LaTeX distribution on Unix systems used to be [teTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeTeX), but it has been superceded by [TeX Live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live).  Most Linux distributions have installation packages for TeX Live--see, for example, the package database entries for [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/texlive) and [Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/packages/name/texlive).
2. You will probably want to install a **LaTeX editor**.  Standard Linux text editors will work fine; in particular, Emacs has a nice package of (La)TeX editing macros called [AUCTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUCTEX).  Specialized LaTeX editors also exist; of those, [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) (KDE Integrated LaTeX Environment) is particularly nice.
3. You will probably want a **LaTeX tutorial**.  The classic tutorial is "[A (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort)," but nowadays the [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) might be a better choice.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend start using Lyx, with that you can use Latex just as easy as OOO-Writer.
It gives you the possibility to step into Latex deeper by manually adding Latex-Code to your Document. 
PDF is just one klick away after installatioin. [Lyx is cross-plattform.](http://www.lyx.org/)

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your Linux distibution and your preference of editors etc. but I would recommend to start with [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) (a KDE app) as it is easy to learn and installing it should install most of the needed packages for LaTex and PDF generation. Just have a look at the screenshots.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Ubuntu or Debian, I made a tutorial easy to follow: [Install LaTeX on Ubuntu or Debian](http://milq.github.io/install-latex-ubuntu-debian). This tutorial explains how to install LaTeX and how to create your first PDF.

Comment: This link is on GitHub but has cookies and ads embedded in a one page super primitive tutorial. I would call this a click bait don't know if others agree.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX comes with most Linux distributions in the form of the [teTeX](http://www.tug.org/tetex/) distribution.  Find all packages with 'teTeX' in the name and install them.

- Most editors such as [vim](http://www.vim.org) or [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) come with TeX [editing modes](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_252.html).  You can also get WYSIWIG-ish front-ends (technically [WYSIWYM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM)), of which perhaps the best known is [LyX.](http://www.lyx.org/)
- The best quick intro to LaTeX is Oetiker's ['The not so short intro to LaTeX'](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/)
- LaTeX works like a compiler.  You compile the LaTeX document (which can include other files), which generates a file called a [`.dvi`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_independent_file_format) (device independent).  This can be post-processed to various formats (including PDF) with various post-processors.
- To do PDF, use [`dvips`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dvips) and use the flag -PPDF (IIRC - I don't have a makefile to hand) to produce a PS with font rendering set up for conversion to pdf.  PDF conversion can then be done with [`ps2pdf`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/6.50/Ps2pdf.htm) or distiller (if you have this).
- The best format for [including graphics](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/figures.html) in this environment is [`eps`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) (Encapsulated Postscript) although not all software produces well-behaved postscript.  Photographs in jpeg or other formats can be included using [various mechanisms.](http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/GF/bibliog/latex/figures.html)

Comment: teTeX is very old and unsupported. TeX Live should be used instead. Otherwise your other comments are good.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the distribution bundled with both Fedora and Ubuntu is teTeX.  It certainly was quite recently.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use a complete editing package such as:

- TexWorks
- TexStudio

Then I would install "MikTeX" as the compiling package, which allows you to generate a PDF from your document, using the `pdfLaTeX` compiler.

Answer (score 2):

```
yum -y install texlive
```

was not enough for my centos distro to get the latex command.

This site https://gist.github.com/melvincabatuan/350f86611bc012a5c1c6  contains additional packages. In particular:

```
yum -y install texlive texlive-latex texlive-xetex
```

was enough but the author also points out these as well:

```
yum -y install texlive-collection-latex
yum -y install texlive-collection-latexrecommended
yum -y install texlive-xetex-def
yum -y install texlive-collection-xetex
```

Only if needed:

```
yum -y install texlive-collection-latexextra
```