# What LaTeX Editor do you suggest for Linux?

Tags: latex, editor

What LaTeX editor do you suggest? Could you please give me some links?

Comment: Sounds like an Editor war question (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war) ^_^

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017055/get-started-with-latex-on-linux and probably others...

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017055/get-started-with-latex-on-linux. That question is more general and this question is specifically looking at LaTeX editors and their advantages or disadvantages.

Comment: Closed as not constructive but I served.
Think TeX editor> Google> StackOverflow> SOLUTION in only four click, thanks!

Comment: See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://goo.gl/3f1mL).

Comment: [TeXstudio](http://www.texstudio.org)

Comment: Not constructuve? 135 upvotes for the question, dozens of upvotes in the answers indicates otherwise.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors

Answer (score 132):

I use [TeXMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/). If you're using Ubuntu, it should be in the apt-get repository. To install `texmaker`, run:

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

Comment: ... or TeXMakerX (http://texmakerx.sourceforge.net/) which is mainly TeXMaker with spell checking and some other features.

Comment: if you install texmaker using apt-get, then it will install the whole texlive distribution, what if someone uses a vanilla texlive from ctan?

Comment: at the moment it requires 1308Mb of space. Outstanding

Answer (score 43):

Gummi is the best LaTeX editor.  It is a free, open source, cross-platform, program, featuring a live preview pane.

http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/

[e4 http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/wp-content/uploads/20091012-1large(1).png](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/wp-content/uploads/20091012-1large(1).png)

Comment: I like Gummi too. It is not written in Python, but in C

Comment: Gummi looks nice and may be promising, but its still lacking some crucial functionality (like tabs to switch opened files without having to use the menu).

Comment: lack of auto-completion sucks big time. else it would have been a top-notch editor.

Comment: Gummi is good but has still many shortcomings. For example when you start it up it opens up a default latex document which is truly annoying.

Comment: A default document can be changed in options, though.

Comment: like gummi, but miss to be able to jump curser in preveiw document to meta and back again.

Answer (score 16):

I normally use Emacs (it has everything you need included).

Of course, there are other options available:

- [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) is KDE's LaTeX editor; it's excellent if you're just learning or if you prefer the integrated environment approach;
- [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) is a WYSIWYG editor that uses LaTeX as a backend; i.e. you tell it what the text should look like and it generates the corresponding LaTeX

Cheers.

Comment: Anyone have recent experiences with LyX?  Back when I tried, it felt really awkward to the point that I'd rather work with the LaTeX source.  I don't know if it was poorly implemented or I just have a fundamental aversion to WYSIWYG LaTeX.

Comment: @Joel: It's much better now.  I tried it out with version 1.3, hated it, and recently started using 1.7.  The change tracking facility is very good, and is integrated with its built in version control.  LyX's native format is sane, you can meaninfully do diffs by hand on it.  Sometimes I use in it preference to Emacs/Auctex.

Answer (score 10):

In Linux it's more likely that extensions to existing editors will be more mature than entirely new ones.  Thus, the two stalwarts (vi and emacs) are likely to have packages available.

EDIT: Indeed, here's the vi one:

http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/

... and here's the emacs one:

http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/

I have to say, I'm a vi man, but the emacs package looks rather spiffy: it includes the ability to embed preview images of formulas in your emacs buffer.

Comment: For someone less hardcore but used to IDE-like editors I would suggest using Atom + packages{ latex_plus, pdf_view, tree_view }. You would have to 'sudo apt-get install latexmk'. On the bright side, you get a sleek editor without Lyx clumsiness with responsive interface, spellcheck and easy ctrl+alt+b build

Answer (score 9):

Honestly, I've always been happy with [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). Then again, I started out using emacs, so I've no doubt that it colours my perceptions. Still, it gives syntax highlighting and formatting, and can easily be configured to build the LaTeX. Check out the [TeX mode](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_252.html).

Comment: Hmmm... auctex > tex-mode

Answer (score 6):

There is a pretty good list at [linuxappfinder.com](http://linuxappfinder.com/office/texlatexeditors).

My personal preference for LaTeX on Linux has been the KDE-based editor [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

When I started to use Latex, I used Eclipse with the texlipse plugin. That allowed me to use the same environment in Linux and Windows, has some auto completion features and runs all tools (latex, bibtex, makeindex, ...) automatically to fully build the project.

But now I switched. Eclipse is large and slow on my PCs, crashes often and shows some weird behaviour here and there. Now I use vim for editing and make in collaboration with a self written perl script to build my projects.
Using cygwin I am still able to use the same work flows under Linux and Windows.