# Mac Tex Environment

Tags: macos, latex, editor

I'm looking for a TeX environment for Mac OS, a bit like [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) for windows. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is better suited to superuser.com

Comment: You got a point there, though after reading
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270121/best-latex-editor-for-windows">this question</a> and <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235043/what-latex-editor-do-you-suggest-for-linux">this qeustion</a> I thought it would be OK to put it here.

Comment: InRe: SO or SU. I'm torn on this one. LaTeX questions as such seem to the good on SO ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow ), though "what software" questions might be better on SU from first principles, but that ends up splitting the accumulated knowledge base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [ii2](http://ii2.sourceforge.net/tex-index.html) to manage LaTeX software for the back end and I have used both TextMate (it has a very nice LaTeX bundle) and Emacs (with Auctex) as front ends.

You can get a nice baked-in LaTeX experience in Emacs by using the Aquamacs distribution (I can't use it because I have a non-english keyboard with no Aquamacs-specific mapping. This makes it impossible to use Aquamacs and the '@' symbol at the same time for me).

More important than all of this, especially if you are embarking on a big project like a thesis, get the [LaTeX Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201362996). It will save you tens to hundreds of hours over the course of a large project.

There are also the Mac-specific LaTeX authoring programs:

- [TeXShop](http://www.uoregon.edu/~koch/texshop/)
- [iTexMac2](http://itexmac.sourceforge.net/iTeXMac2.html)
- [TeXMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/)
- [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) (this is somewhat "non-standard", as it abstracts slightly over LaTeX and has its own file format, ".lyx")
- [Texmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/) (this has the great feature of being written in Scheme)

There is a Mac-specific LaTeX back end called [Mactex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: i-Installer is no longer supported. Use MacTeX instead.

Comment: That shows you how often I need to renew my LaTeX installation (basically, when I get a new computer).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/) distribution.  The TeX distribution that it comes with is TeX Live 2008, which is newer than the TeX distribution available though [i-Installer](http://ii2.sourceforge.net/) (a.k.a ii2).  MacTeX also comes with the [TeX Live Utility](http://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/), a graphical interface for the [TeX Live package manager](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) for installing, updating, or otherwise managing (La)TeX packages.  It also comes with [TeXShop](http://www.uoregon.edu/~koch/texshop/texshop.html), a (La)TeX editor that is comparable to TeXnicCenter (I personally like it much better than TeXnicCenter).

Answer (score 1):

I use LaTeX on my Mac for all my documents.  I'm very happy with the MacTex installation I downloaded. I think it's a bundle of TeXLive for the Mac. I use Carbon Emacs for file writing and editing, I don't recall any installation or configuration problems getting it to work with LaTeX.  If memory serves me well, though, the MacTex installation includes a more GUI-like editor too.

Answer (score 0):

I install the [tetex](http://www.tug.org/tetex/) distribution from [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), and edit in the fink-install carbon-emacs with auctex.

The result is a vanilla unix-like tex environment, and possibly not what you're looking for (though not knowing anything about TeXnicCenter, or hy *you* like it I can't say).

Comment: teTeX is very old and unsupported. Use MacTeX instead.

Comment: @Will: I'd agree with you if the installation was any work at all, but I use fink for all my "unix" services, and the effort is `fink list tex` followed by `fink install tetex auctex revtex`.

Comment: You can install texlive from fink, which is the successor project to tetex, and include a "textex-like" subinstallation. Fink's texlive package is not up-to-date (it is a year behind at the moment), but that's a whole lot more up-to-date than tetex.

Answer (score 0):

[MacTex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/) with [texlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) plugin for eclipse. It works properly! ;)